# telegram bot cant access bot message in the group

Tags: node.js, api, telegram, telegram-bot

**This is not duplicate :|**

I added a new bot for manage the gorup. by this info:

- my bot is admin
- my bot privacy disabled

> 'Enable' - your bot will only receive messages that either start with
>   the '/' symbol or mention the bot by username. 'Disable' - your bot
>   will receive all messages that people send to groups. Current status
>   is: DISABLED Success! The new status is: DISABLED

bot can read all members except other bots messages!
but can see information on reply.

my tg api is: https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 bots talking to eachother may cause an infinite loop! So, bots don't get update messages from other bots.

Comment: Do you have reference for this description?

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots